# Knex.js update function saving as [object Object] in SQLite database instead of stringified JSON

Tags: javascript, sqlite, knex.js

I have Knex.js setup with an SQLite database. When I create an entry via the `insert` function, it correctly converts the JSON fields into strings. When updating using the `update` function, it inserts [object Object] into the database column instead.

For example, say we have the table `card` with columns `id` (int), `name` (string), and `service` (string).

Creating an entry with:

```
const value = {
  name: 'test name',
  service: {
    domain: 'test domain'
  }
}

knex('card').insert(value).returning('*');
```

Inserts the row:

| id | name | service |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | {"domain":"test domain"} |

Then updating with:

```
const updateValue = {
  name: 'test name',
  service: {
    domain: 'updated domain'
  }
}

knex('card').where('id', 1).update(updateValue).returning('*');
```

Updates the row to:

| id | name | service |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | [object Object] |

Is this the intended behavior? I need the `service` column to remain a stringified version of the JSON so that I can parse it on the frontend.

I set it up with a very stripped-down version so I can clearly see exactly what is being sent to the database. I can see that the format of the incoming object is identical for creating and updating the entry, so I'm not sure why it's not updating correctly.

Comment: The documentation is pretty poor but does the result of your code not tell you the answer? Yes, it seems intentional even if difficult to comprehend. Seems you should stringify the `service` property

Answer (score -1):

const updateValue = {
name: 'test name',
service: {
domain: 'updated domain'
}
}

knex('card').where('id', 1).update({name : updateValue.name, service : updateValue.service.toString()}).returning('*');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).